# Infinite "Xamarin iOS SDK Update Available" message

Tags: xamarin

I have updated (Beta channel) my Mac and Visual Studio 2013 to the newest everything. However when I run VS2013, I get the message that a SDK update is available. So I update. Reboot and run VS2013 again. Then the message appears again. Repeat.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you able to deploy to an iPhone still?

Comment: Try alternating maybe to alpha/stable and back.

Answer (score 0):

Go up to Xamarin.com and install Xamarin from there.  Updating from there cleared this annoyance for me.